# postgresql version is not getting uninstall

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgresql version 9.5.3. Now I am trying to uninstall this and I want to install version 9.4 as per documents needed.

I have executed a command:

```
 sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql
```

But when I hit `$ pg_config --version` it still showing version of postgresql 9.5.3.

Can any one help me to rid out of this problem?

Comment: Hi Rohan What OS do you have? Its totally ok to run more than one version of postgresql at the same time. What does psql say ? This may help with the versions ->psql --cluster postgresl-version/main --version

Comment: I am running on ubuntu version 14.04...

Comment: Thanks Rohan  What does -> dpkg -l | grep postgres give you? It might be that unbuntu install postgresql in parts. all the best

Comment: apt-get autoremove postgresql

Comment: Thanks pnorton... actually to remove postgresql version we also need to remove its client with command  $ sudo apt-get remove posgresql-client-(version of postgresql).... before run 
   
apt-get autoremove postgresql ... combination of both will gives you the actuall result